# How do I create a logical OR from a list of Expression<Func<T, bool>>

Tags: nhibernate

I am building an NHibernate `QueryOver<T>` from a list of `Expression<Func<T, bool>>`. Right now my object iterates the list and adds the expressions using `queryOver.Where(item)` which is treated as a logical AND. I now wish to change this so that given a specified parameter, it switches to append the items using a logical OR, but I can't figure out how to do this... can anyone give me a pointer in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically building the restriction criteria with ORs isn't particularly straight-forward. The method found in [Joel Potter's blog post](http://www.methodicmadness.com/2012/04/extending-queryover-with-or.html) is quite good. This approach uses an extension method to add an `Or` method to the QueryOver API that accepts an array of `ICriterion`.

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static IQueryOver<troot, tsubtype> 
          Or<troot, tsubtype>(this IQueryOver<troot, tsubtype> input, ICriterion[] criteria)
  {
    if (criteria.Length == 0)
      return input;
    else if (criteria.Length == 1)
      return input.Where(criteria[0]);
    else
    {
      var or = Restrictions.Or(criteria[0], criteria[1]);
      for (int i = 2; i < criteria.Length; i++)
        or = Restrictions.Or(or, criteria[i]);

      return input.Where(or);
    }
  }
}
```

This extension method can then be used to construct the `OR`ed constraints:

```
var l = new List<ICriterion>();
foreach(var item in expressionList)
  l.Add(Restrictions.Where(item));

s.QueryOver<Order>()
  .Or(l.ToArray())
  .List();
```

This should produce the results you require.